# VS code terminal for python is not showing output. help me to fix it

Tags: python, visual-studio

I tried to run the code but this comes. anyone knows how to fix it I tried reinstall vs studio. and every possible option on the internet.

[image: img]

Comment: Why don't you try and add python path to the environment variables in Windows?

Comment: Do you call the main function?

Comment: “Every possible option on the internet”?  I find this a bit hard to believe.

Answer (score 0):

You never call your main function

```
def main():
    x = 0
    print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```